# C# WCF Service Reference - can not create UserNameToken

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, usernametoken

In my desktop application (C#, WPF, WCF, .NET4.0) I addes a service reference.

This is Web Service (SOAP) using certificate and UserNameToken in Soap Envelope Header.

I add service reference (Solution -> Service Reference -> Add Service Reference) using WSDL of this web service.
In my app.config I have got:

```
    <customBinding>
<binding name="tmsIntegrationServiceSOAP">
          <!--    WsdlImporter encountered unrecognized policy assertions in ServiceDescription 'urn:CDM/tmsIntegrationService/':    -->
          <!--    <wsdl:binding name='tmsIntegrationServiceSOAP'>    -->
          <!--        <sp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">..</sp:SupportingTokens>    -->
          <mtomMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
          <httpsTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>

<endpoint address="https://XXX/CDM/tmsIntegrationService"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="tmsIntegrationServiceSOAP"
        contract="RABEN.GS1.tmsIntegrationService" name="tmsIntegrationServiceSOAP" />
```

I'm passing user name and password like this:

```
var ssc = new GS1.tmsIntegrationServiceClient();
ssc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
ssc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "testPassword";
ssc.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new InspectorBehavior());
```

When I get the request XML (with message inspector) I see that there is no UserNameToken in soap header

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">urn:CDM/tmsIntegrationService/importTransportInstruction</Action>
    <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPoy3hcoBMqQ5Kme7yqEiHKs0AAAAAyxy+QnWD8U60kqJZWaGfvYD8RN14nUVIjC0RuEyVBa8ACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body ...
```

I try to user basicHttpBinding:

```
<binding name="secured">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>

<endpoint address="https://XXX/CDM/tmsIntegrationService"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secured" contract="RABEN.GS1.tmsIntegrationService"
        name="tmsIntegrationServiceSOAP" />
```

End the result:

```
<s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">urn:CDM/tmsIntegrationService/importTransportInstruction</Action>
  </s:Header>
```

When i try to use wsHttpBinding:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="RabenBinding">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>

<endpoint address="https://XXX/CDM/tmsIntegrationService"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RabenBinding"
        contract="RABEN.GS1.tmsIntegrationService" name="tmsIntegrationServiceSOAP" />
```

The result:

```
<s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">urn:CDM/tmsIntegrationService/importTransportInstruction</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:701a0fff-c4aa-4f37-a299-ec6d272e51e7</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
  </s:Header>
```

Could some one tell me what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT - 2017-06-21 20:00
The certificate is installed on my local machine

```
<behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RabenBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="this is footprint of certificate"
              storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

I'm attaching this behavion in endpoint:

```
<endpoint address="https://XXX/CDM/tmsIntegrationService"
        behaviorConfiguration="RabenBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="RabenBinding" contract="RABEN.GS1.tmsIntegrationService"
        name="tmsIntegrationServiceSOAP" />
```

EDIT 2017-06-21 20:58
I try to use  `<mtomMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />`

```
<binding name="myCustomBindingConfig">
          <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default"
                    authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport"
            requireDerivedKeys="true"
          includeTimestamp="false" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10" />
          <mtomMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
          <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000" />
        </binding>
```

But the header is still do not containt user name token

```
<s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">urn:CDM/tmsIntegrationService/importTransportInstruction</Action>
    <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo0OlG2DVOLdKniJmYU2kvwUAAAAAujMM+x53aEWJYYd4GKyk+PlCKXIih9xLrE0V5TayKhQACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
  </s:Header>
```

EDIT 2017-06-21 21:36
Try to use `<textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />` in custom binding generatet by VS

```
<binding name="tmsIntegrationServiceSOAP">
          <!--    WsdlImporter encountered unrecognized policy assertions in ServiceDescription 'urn:CDM/tmsIntegrationService/':    -->
          <!--    <wsdl:binding name='tmsIntegrationServiceSOAP'>    -->
          <!--        <sp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">..</sp:SupportingTokens>    -->
          <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
          <httpsTransport />
        </binding>
```

But it bring no effect - there is no user name token in request XML:

```
<s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">urn:CDM/tmsIntegrationService/importTransportInstruction</Action>
    <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo0wJNixU4QRBhGEUAC3pw50AAAAA/fPJ+e50KUSGbYXwcmoGwgqymCvLXJZIhKg/nKdV97cACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
  </s:Header>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `<textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />` instead of `<mtomMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />` in your custom binding?

Comment: I try this (see edit EDIT 2017-06-21 20:58)

Comment: your edit still contains mtomMessageEncoding

Comment: Sorry, i add new edit (EDIT 2017-06-21 21:36) with textMessageEncoding  - no effect :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

but what happend if you add by click on the solution explorer add service reference, what it is telling you?. Or you don't have this option.

Comment: I edit the question to be more clearly: I add service reference (Solution -> Service Reference -> Add Service Reference) using WSDL of this web service. There is no error when I'm adding service reference

Comment: and doing that ask for accept your certificate and input the user and password if the answer is yes. You might instance it without anything else. Sorry for my english

Comment: check this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mcsuksoldev/2011/07/05/using-mutual-ssl-and-message-security-to-secure-a-wcf-service/

Answer (score 0):

To modify SOAP Header you will need to implement IClientMessageInspector 
interface.To do this create new class MessageInspector and add
three following classes nested in it:

```
public class CustomMessageHeader : MessageHeader
        {
            private const string NAMESPACE_SECURITY = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";
            public CustomMessageHeader()
            {
            }
            public override string Name
            {
                get { return "wsse:Security"; }
            }
            public override string Namespace
            {
                get { return ""; }
            }
            protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
            {
                writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "wsse", null, NAMESPACE_SECURITY);
                writer.WriteStartElement("wsse:UsernameToken");
                writer.WriteElementString("wsse:Username", "YOUR_USERNAME");
                writer.WriteElementString("wsse:Password", "YOUR_PASSWORD");
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }
public class ClientMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
        {
            public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
            {
                CustomMessageHeader header = new CustomMessageHeader();
                request.Headers.RemoveAt(0);
                request.Headers.Add(header);
                return request;
            }
public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
            {
            }
        }
public class CustomEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
        {
public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
            {
                clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new ClientMessageInspector());
            }
public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
            {
            }

            public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
            {
            }

            public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
            {
            }
}
```

To trigger this class to be called, add new Endpoint Behavior in your Main class

```
serviceClient.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new CustomEndpointBehavior());
```